# How to ger rid of "[WARNING]: Consider using dnf module rather than running dnf"?

Tags: ansible, dnf

Some of my ansible playbooks start with installation of `python2-dnf` package that is required for *dnf* ansible module to run.

```yaml
tasks:
- name: Install required dnf python binding
  shell: dnf install -y python2-dnf
  changed_when: False
```

Direct call of `dnf` in *shell* module results in following warning

```
[WARNING]: Consider using dnf module rather than running dnf
```

How such warning can be avoided or what is the suggested way to make sure that package `python2-dnf` is installed and thus module *dnf* can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Shell warnings can be silenced by adding a `warn=no` to your shell command string like this:

`tasks:
- name: Install required dnf python binding
  shell: dnf install -y python2-dnf warn=no
  changed_when: False`